# how to support same column size when screen size reducing in angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui

I do have material table where I am using the 9 columns, I would like to maintain same column size even if the screen reduces.

Currently, When I reduce my screen last column is shirking first which looks bit odd as other groups are still having equal size.

Is there anyway we can support same column size for "total settlement amount"even screen size reduces?

Below is my stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-5foa62?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

[Image Updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaOaQ.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying your problem on my request. for this behavior I would suggest you to use `min-widht` and `max-widht` to make you `table` cell looks similar on every screen, please use below CSS in your stackblitz

```
th.mat-header-cell,
td.mat-cell {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0 !important;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

Also if you want to make first cell look smaller as it is serial numbers so change its `min-width` and `max-width`using `first-child`

```
th.mat-header-cell:first-child,
td.mat-cell:first-child{
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

To change only "**total settlement amount**" as you mentioned in your question then use some CLASS on those cell(`th td`) and style it like above

```
 .similar-cell-width{
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    width: 100px; /*solution as per your req it fix the table cell widht*/

 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have implemented changes but still in some cases, headers are showing different. Please check updated stackblitz

Comment: @app Try using `width:100px` this will solve your problem

Comment: @app `.similar-cell-width{
    width: 100px;
 }` in css, updated my ans as well

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help. Just have one question.. I do have changed my data style and it is behaving weird.. can you please help me, if I have the nested array of objects how i can display in table?

Comment: I have added newData Array. and updated in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-5foa62

Comment: I also added new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347251/how-to-show-split-header-in-the-material-table-having-nested-group-of-data-in-an

Comment: @app Glad to hear that you problem is solved please accept Ans to help others, I am looking into `newData Array` issue i m not sure whether i can help in this as I am also newbie to Angular Material ;p

Comment: I have accepted the answer. Please help on the above question if possible.

Comment: If I add .similar-cell-width{     width: 100px;  } all column size are getting equal... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-rjlidj

Answer (score 1):

Material adds css classes to each td based on your **displayedColumns** array, so you could target each class with css.

```
 displayedColumns: string[] = ['name'];

<td class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-name mat-column-name" > Name </td>
```

CSS

```
 .mat-column-name {max-width: 120px; min-width: 120px;}
```